# Excel: Take on the value of a formula cell when other cell is equal to x?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-excel-2019

I know that title isn’t great but essentially:

Let’s say

A1 = some number

And

A2 = some formula involving A1

I want to store values of A2 in a column for different values of A1 so like a function which sets A1 to some value and the cell takes the value of the resulting A2?

Is there Excel function for this or do you have to make a custom one?

Comment: This will require vba.  Formulas will not do this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way for it currently.

The solution will be the [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/LAMBDA-FUNCTION-BD212D27-1CD1-4321-A34A-CCBF254B8B67) function which will let you easily convert formulas into functions.
Currently (November 2021) it's available for Office testers only

Workaround would be just to copy your formula to several cells.